# Using smsmanagaer is not working in alertbox

Tags: android, sms

smsmanager is not working,its not showing any error also,it function is not working at all,dialog dismiss only working.

Mainactivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FetchDataListener,OnClickListener
    {
        private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        ListView lv;
        private List items;
        private Button btnGetSelected;
        //private ProjectsDbAdapter mDbHelper;
        //private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);  
         //mDbHelper = new ProjectsDbAdapter(this);
            //mDbHelper.open();
            //fillData();
            //registerForContextMenu(getListView());

     lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     btnGetSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnget);
        btnGetSelected.setOnClickListener(this);

        initView();
    }



    private void initView()
    {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://dry-brushlands-3645.herokuapp.com/posts.json";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);

        //mDbHelper.open();     
        //Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
        //startManagingCursor(projectsCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        //String[] from = new String[]{ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        //int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        /* Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter projects = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_row, projectsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(projects);
        */
        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
        //as well as the layout information
         /*dataAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
          this, R.layout.activity_row, 
          projectsCursor, 
          from, 
          to,
          0);
         setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
        */
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
            mi.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); 
        return true;

    }

     @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

                createProject();

            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
     }

     private void createProject() {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ProjectEditActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);   
        }

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            initView();
        }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data)
    {
        this.items = data;
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                Application bean = items.get(position);
                if (bean.isSelected()) {
                    bean.setSelected(false);
                    chk.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    bean.setSelected(true);
                    chk.setChecked(true);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    // Toast is here...
        private void showToast(String msg) {
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg)
    {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        // Retrive Data from list
        for (Application bean : items) {

            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                sb.append(Html.fromHtml(bean.getContent()));
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }

        showAlertView(sb.toString().trim());

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void showAlertView(String str) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
            alert.setTitle("Not Selected");
            alert.setMessage("No One is Seleceted!!!");
        } else {
            // Remove , end of the name
            String strContactList = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

            alert.setTitle("Selected");
            alert.setMessage(strContactList);
        }
        alert.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //sendSMS();
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }


        });

        In my code i am using sms manager for sending sms which are the thing getting from my listview,it has to send sms,but after clicking the ok button,nothing is work, dialog dismiss only working,not sms manager is not working.
```

Comment: smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null); sending to whom?? "phoneno"

Comment: i want that it has to get number from myside and sms message want that data which is in the alertbox @Tarun

Answer (score 0):

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

"phoneNo" in this place specify the number for which you want to send sms

ok what is that selected data does that contain the phone numbers or the some text data that needs to be sent as a message. see "phoneNo" is string what you are passing. In your phone in place of number if you type phoneNo how will it send to which number will it send. that 1st parameter is the phone number to which you want to send sms. if you are selecting the phone number from the list get that to a variable and put that variable in place of  "phoneNo"

if you want to enter the number when the alert is shown then here is the code

```
private void showAlertView(String str) {
    final EditText input = new EditText(YOURACTIVITYNAME.this);
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(YOURACTIVITYNAME.this)
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
        alert.setTitle("Not Selected");
        alert.setMessage("No One is Seleceted!!!");
    } else {
        // Remove , end of the name
        String strContactList = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

        alert.setTitle("Selected");
        alert.setMessage(strContactList);
    }
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 String value;

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //sendSMS();

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(input.getText().toString(), null, "sms message", null, null);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
            }).show();
```

Comment: @prvn--i want like this..listview having checkbox,after checked the listview,and then click the top of getselected button,it will shows what are the thing we selected in the alertbox with ok button,What i want is if i click the ok button ,it has to send sms with the selected data